# How can I see whether there is an intersection between an object and array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Suppose I have 2 json objects and I want to see whether there is a match/intersection based on the ids . These are the 2 objects:

```
 obj=   {
      "container_copy": {
        "card1": {
          "id": "300",
          "copy": "hello"
        },
        "card2": {
          "id": "1000",
          "type": "card"
        },
        "text": "bla"
      }
    }
```

and

```
   items= [{id:"103",text:'hello'}, {id:"11",text:'yo'}]
```

I tried this:

```
 let o1 = _.keyBy(_.values(obj), 'id');
 let o2 = _.keyBy(items, 'id');
 let inter = _.intersection(_.keys(o1), _.keys(o2));
 let result = _.chain(o1)
            .pick(inter)
            .merge(_.pick(o2, inter))
            .value();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_.values` returns an array so you need to take the first element when assigning a value to `o1`: `_.keyBy(_.values(obj)[0], 'id')`

Comment: what result are you expecting for your example? I don't fully understand what you mean by "match/intersection based on the ids"...